# unable to query on RDBMS using apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

With apache drill 1.2, we can query over RDBMS data. Check more here: https://drill.apache.org/blog/2015/10/16/drill-1.2-released/

so, I tried to add a plugin for MySQL. I am doing it using the web client. I created a plugin with name `mysql` and added following configurations:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "uri": "jdbc:mysql://<IP>:3306/classicmodels",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Also, I added `mysql.jar` in `/apache-drill-1.2.0/jars/3rdparty`

It is showing error:

> (Invalid JSON mapping)

Any pointer on this. Is there any documentation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to add storage plugin for MySQL:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:mysql://<IP>",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "enabled": true
}
```

noticed **url** instead of  **uri**.

After adding plugin, query can be done using:

```
select * from mysql.classicmodels.`customers`;
```

where `classicmodels` is Database name & `customers` table name.

Comment: Don't use the products table of the classicmodels database, and maybe other tables that use the TEXT type, due unresolved issues: http://drill.apache.org/docs/apache-drill-1-2-0-release-notes/#important-unresolved-issues. To test the Drill connection, you can use the performance_schema and a query, e.g., select * from myplugin.performance_schema.accounts;

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for bumping out. I've got a similar issue while creating Storage/Configurations. When including the configurations under plugin creation, it says a `Unable to create/update storage`. Did you encounter this issue while creating a storage plugin? I followed the [docs from drill](http://www.scalerlabs.io/blog/apache-drill-exploring-connecting-to-rdbms-via-jdbc/)

EDIT:

Drill does test connection on the fly when creating the plugin. The machine wasn't up at the time of creating the plugin. When the machine was back, it worked.