# unable to configure postgreSQL JDBC driver using apache drill 1.2

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, rdbms, apache-drill

With apache drill 1.2, we can query over RDBMS data https://drill.apache.org/blog/2015/10/16/drill-1.2-released/

I downloaded the JDBC PostgreSQL driver here:
 https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
I took the JDBC4 I didn't know which to take.

I put the jar file in this folder 'apache-drill-1.2.0\jars\3rdparty'

And now, I'm trying to add a plugin for postgres. I am doing it using the web console (http://127.0.0.1:8047). I created a plugin with name pgplugin and added following configurations:

`{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:postgresql://IP:port/myschema",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "enabled": true
}`

It is showing error:
error(Unable to create / update storage)

Even with just the following it's not working (same error):

`{
  "type": "jdbc"
}`

I know that I should add the jar (jdbc postgres driver) to apache drill classpath somewhere in the configuration files but I can't figure it out...

I tried to add this: `drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"`

to the `drill-override.conf` -> result is:

`drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"
}`

But it's not working... any ideas ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: The jar, don't know which one exactly, belongs in <drill_installation_directory>/jars/3rdparty (see the docs: http://drill.apache.org/docs/jdbc-storage-plugin/), I saw a user report a problem using the new driver with postgres. I don't see a public JIRA about it yet, but the Drill developers know about the possible bug.

Comment: Re: your postgres driver choice, JDBC4 cannot be the right one. The download page you referenced says java 1.7 matches JDBC41. If everything is on the same node and you are using 1.7 then using the JDBC41 version to be consistent is probably a good idea (if not required). Drill requires JDK 1.7. I'm not sure that using the correct driver will ensure success because of the reported problem I mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I'll try other JDBC drivers.
In the same time, I tried using the Mysql driver, but I have the same issue. I downloaded the jar, put it in the 3rdparty folder. But then I don't know what to do for apache drill to use it. 
In documentation, it's written to add 
drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar" in the conf file, but I still have an an error when I try to create my configuration file (i use the same example than there 
drill.apache.org/docs/jdbc-storage-plugin) thanks

Comment: The drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath" is for storage plugin persistance (see http://drill.apache.org/docs/storage-plugin-registration/#storage-plugin-configuration-persistance). "/mypath" should be a directory on your file system, such as /tmp. Setup a MySQL password, make sure MySQL is running before starting the Drill shell. "mypassword" is not the default MySQL password--the default is no password. That won't work. The right MySQL command to change the password depends on your OS and MySQL version. Try logging in on the MySQL command line to test your password.

Comment: @user2594988 I am able to query over mysql. check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232644/unable-to-query-on-rdbms-using-apache-drill

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm able to query using MySQL! 
I'm still having issues with postgres though. Don't get why.. The storage plugin error is not very detailed :)

Comment: If you're willing to experiment, a Drill 1.3 preview fixes several JDBC storage plugin issues, and some of them are definitely postgres-related: http://people.apache.org/~jacques/apache-drill-1.3.0.rc0/ (haven't tried it yet)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue.  The cause of my problem was using the "JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1205" JDBC driver.  I fixed this issue by using the "JDBC4 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1205" driver.

For reference, the Postgres JDBC downloads page: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html