# Apache Drill 1.2 and SQL Server JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-drill

Apache Drill 1.2 adds the exciting feature of including JDBC relational sources in your query. I would like to include Microsoft SQL Server.

So, following the docs I copied the SQL Server jar sqldjbc42.jar (the most recent MS JDBC driver) into the proper 3rd party directory.

I successfully added the storage.

The configuration is:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://myservername",
  "username": "myusername",
  "password": "mypassword",
  "enabled": true
}
```

as "mysqlserverstorage"

However, running queries fails. I've tried:

```
select * from mysqlserverstorage.databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

(of course I've use real existing tables instead of the placeholders here)

Error:

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 2, column 6 to line 2, column 17: Table 'mysqlserverstorage.databasename.schemaname.tablename' not found [Error Id: f5b68a73-973f-4292-bdbf-54c2b6d5d21e on PC1234:31010]

and

```
select * from mysqlserverstorage.`databasename.schemaname.tablename`
```

Error:

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: Exception while reading tables [Error Id: 213772b8-0bc7-4426-93d5-d9fcdd60ace8 on PC1234:31010]

Has anyone had success in configuring and using this new feature?

Comment: can you try `select * from mysqlserverstorage.databasename.tablename`

Comment: Does not work either, different error:
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: DATA_READ ERROR: The JDBC storage plugin failed while trying setup the SQL query. sql SELECT * FROM "_Databasename_"."_Tablename_" plugin sqldwh Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: 88aaa505-48ae-4ccc-9ff3-ceda878c2734 on PC1234:31010]

Comment: don't know much about  Microsoft SQL server.  I tried for MySQL. Check it may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232644/unable-to-query-on-rdbms-using-apache-drill

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if you want to experiment this Drill 1.3 preview, it fixes several JDBC storage plugin issues: http://people.apache.org/~jacques/apache-drill-1.3.0.rc0/. Tip: re: mssql 3-part naming, use one storage plugin config connection for just one mssql database.

Comment: The success really wasn't what I thought--he didn't use the plugin.

Comment: Real success connecting to sqlserver has been reported. The key was using the SQL jar specified on https://goo.gl/K8KDYl

Answer (score 1):

Success has been reported using a storage plugin configuration, such as

```
{
  type: "jdbc",
  enabled: true,
  driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  url:"jdbc:sqlserver://172.31.36.88:1433;databaseName=msdb",
  username:"root",
  password:"<password>"
}
```

on pre-release [Drill 1.3](http://people.apache.org/~jacques/apache-drill-1.3.0.rc2/) and using [sqljdbc41.4.2.6420.100.jar](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/details.aspx?id=11774).

Answer (score 1):

Construct you query as,

select * from storagename.schemaname.tablename

This will work with sqljdbc4.X as it works for me.